# Difference between MsiInstallProduct and Installer.InstallProduct?

Tags: deployment, installation, wix, windows-installer, dtf

What's the difference between these two?

[MsiInstallProduct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370315.aspx) and [Installer.InstallProduct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). From what I've read, the only difference is that the first returns an int that will dictate if the installation succeeded or not.

I am currently using DTF (WiX) to call `Installer.InstallProduct`. The problem is, this function has a return type of void.

Question:
How can I determine if the installation succeeded or not when calling `Installer.InstallProduct` via DTF?

Comment: It's common for managed API wrappers to change failing return codes into thrown exceptions, leaving successful return codes as void returns. Is that the case here?

Comment: Sorry Michael, didn't see your comment.  Yes, that's what is going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed, MsiInstallProduct simply returns error or success with no further information.   Installer.InstallProduct returns nothing.   DTF returns nothing.

Why the difference?  MsiInstallProduct is old school C/C++ where you return error codes.   The others are new school where instead you  raise exceptions.   Your code then catches the exception to know that there was a problem.